# Iterating through JSON file in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, json, object, iterator, fs

I am trying to iterate through a json file where this is the template of the file:

```json
[
    {
        "REF_DATE": 2016,
        "GEO": "Canada",
        "DGUID": "2016A11124",
        "Educational qualification": "Career, technical or professional training certificate",
        "Field of study": "Total, field of study",
        "Gender": "Total, gender",
        "Age group": "15 to 64 years",
        "Status of student in Canada": "Canadian and international students",
        "Characteristics after graduation": "Graduates reporting employment income",
        "Graduate statistics": "Number of graduates",
        "UOM": "Number",
        "UOM_ID": 223,
        "SCALAR_FACTOR": "units",
        "SCALAR_ID": 0,
        "VECTOR": "v1007923968",
        "COORDINATE": "1.2.1.1.1.1.4.1",
        "VALUE": 33930,
        "STATUS": "",
        "SYMBOL": "",
        "TERMINATED": "",
        "DECIMALS": 0
    },
    {
        "REF_DATE": 2016,
        "GEO": "Canada",
        "DGUID": "2016A11124",
        "Educational qualification": "Career, technical or professional training certificate",
        "Field of study": "Education [1]",
        "Gender": "Total, gender",
        "Age group": "15 to 64 years",
        "Status of student in Canada": "Canadian and international students",
        "Characteristics after graduation": "Graduates reporting employment income",
        "Graduate statistics": "Number of graduates",
        "UOM": "Number",
        "UOM_ID": 223,
        "SCALAR_FACTOR": "units",
        "SCALAR_ID": 0,
        "VECTOR": "v1007929890",
        "COORDINATE": "1.2.2.1.1.1.4.1",
        "VALUE": 865,
        "STATUS": "",
        "SYMBOL": "",
        "TERMINATED": "",
        "DECIMALS": 0
    }
]
```

I basically want to look through the entire document, and pull only certain elements ("Educational qualification" and "VALUE") from these objects into an array, if they match certain conditions (have the same "Field of study" and "UOM_ID"). I want to return this array in a get api request.

I currently have a helper function to read the jsonFile:

```js
function jsonReader(dataAddress, cb) {
    fs.readFile(dataAddress, (err, fileData) => {
      if (err) {
        return cb && cb(err);
      }
      try {
        const object = JSON.parse(fileData);
        return cb && cb(null, object);
      } catch (err) {
        return cb && cb(err);
      }
    });
}
```

I also have a get request written that currently returns the entire json file.

```js
app.get('/income/:job', (req, res)=>{
    
    jsonReader('./data.json', (err, result) => {
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            res.send(result);
        }
    })

});
```

Can I please get some assistance on how to accomplish this task? I have tried looking through many youtube videos and forums, and can't find much help. Thanks a lot!

Comment: What is the structure of the data looks like in the file, is it an array of Objects or something else?

Comment: Yep, that's the structure.

[
    {
        data
    },
    {
        data
    }
]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you have managed to read the data from a file as text and then use JSON.parse( ) to convert it to an object. That is a good start.

There are two ways of doing this, here is one I use quite often.You can use Object.keys( ) to get a list of all the property names in your object. Then its just a matter of creating a new object and only copying the desired keys and properties to it from the original object. This example puts the results in a new object rather than an array, but using an array would largely be no different unless you wanted to use numeric indexes.

```
var output = {};
var keys = Object.keys(object);
var key = null;
for (key of Keys){
      if(key === "MATCHING_PROPERTY_NAME")
            if(object[key] === "MATCHING_VALUE")
                   output[key]= object[key];
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I will go ahead and try this.

Comment: I hope it helps you out. As you are a new member can I remind you that If it helped then please mark it accordingly.